# cmake & gcc compiles every file every time

Tags: gcc, cmake

I'm a learning c++ developer writing a game initially on the Mac platform using XCode, but now moving to cross platform by leveraging CMake. So far I can get it compiled on my ickle linux netbook and I'm putting together a dev environment on this machine for on the go coding. However I'm finding that gcc recompiles every file whenever I make a change. Clearly I need some additional configuration to the CMakeLists.txt . My current one is very simple. Like so;

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8)
set (source
Creature.cpp
DisplayManager.cpp
Engine.cpp
EngineState.cpp
Entity.cpp
GameWorld.cpp
GfxSFML.cpp
Item.cpp
Map.cpp
Position.cpp
Projectile.cpp
ScreenTile.cpp
SquadAI.cpp
Terrain.cpp
UIButton.cpp
UICharPanel.cpp
UIView.cpp
Utility.cpp
Weapon.cpp
fov.cpp
main.cpp
)

find_package (OpenAL)
find_package (OpenGL)
find_package (SFML)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-g -Wall -pg")
add_executable (tractionedge ${source})
target_link_libraries(tractionedge ${SFML_LIBRARY} ${OPENGL_LIBRARY} ${OPENAL_LIBRARY})
```

I've concentrated so far on C++ as a language rather than build systems by sticking with XCode for everything. My knowledge of Autotools (make?) and Gcc is very limited. How do I have gcc only recompile the changed source?

Answer (score 10):

Are you rerunning `cmake` every time?  If you just modify one source file, you should be able to simply rerun `make`, and it should rebuild just the one object file before linking.  If you rerun `cmake`, it might mark all of the source files dirty and rebuild everything.

Only rerun `cmake` if you change the actual list of source files being used, or other major changes like that.

Comment: In fact you could still just run `make` since that will check to see if any dependencies have been updated.

Comment: This is only exposing the poor quality of work that is cmake. Wait for the beta to release.

Answer (score 6):

Rebuilding only the modified sources SHOULD be the default behavior. Of course if you change a central header included by nearly all dependent cpp files it'll trigger a nearly complete rebuild. Look at what happens if you only modify one cpp file (adding a comment or alike), if more than that compilation unit is compiling then I propose you to invest more time investigating it eventually giving you my EMail to have a deeper look at the configuration.

Another possibility is that you are compiling under windows and using a 2.8 cmake that has a bug regarding this. Look at a 2.9 version to see if that defect is away then: http://www.mail-archive.com/cmake@cmake.org/msg24876.html

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite your CMakeLists.txt using glob (maybe move the files in a "src" directory if you have other *.cpp files around) and give your project a name (this sets some important variables):

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8)
project(TRACTION)
file (GLOB TRACTION_SOURCES *.cpp)
find_package (OpenAL)
find_package (OpenGL)
find_package (SFML)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-g -Wall -pg")
add_executable (tractionedge ${TRACTION_SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(tractionedge ${SFML_LIBRARY} ${OPENGL_LIBRARY} ${OPENAL_LIBRARY})
```

Comment: You should not use `GLOB()` since if you add a new `.cpp` file, CMake will not know about it and so will not automatically re-run. In this case you would have to manually run cmake again, forcing a complete rebuild of everything.

Comment: I disagree. Look at some big projects with tons of src files (opencv), they use GLOB everywhere, and yes, they rerun cmake when new files are added (but that's something you have to do anyway): "cmake" is less of a burden then edit the CMakeLists and ... run cmake to update the makefiles !!

Comment: Milliams, you're all wrong, I just tested running "cmake" after a complete (and large) build: that does not mark all files as dirty.

Comment: as a rule the use of GLOB is discouraged see https://gist.github.com/mbinna/c61dbb39bca0e4fb7d1f73b0d66a4fd1

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced unnecessary rebuilds using cmake and visual studio. The problem is related to an inappropriate x64 configuration parameter: [Visual Studio 2008 Unnecessary Project Building](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/567939/visual-studio-2008-unnecessary-project-building)

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution in many of these cases is to completely wipe the build tree and regenerate it (and I mean something along the lines of `rm -rf build && mkdir build && cd build && cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" ../src`, not just `make clean`)

Comment: Ya, Sometimes the cached variables are culprits .