# Build only modifiyed projects?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, build

I have a Solution with several Projects, is there some kind of versioning control within VS2010, so on build only projects with modifiyed files to be rebuilded?

Comment: See if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/567939/visual-studio-2008-unnecessary-project-building/775272#775272) helps.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov, thanks, I didn't saw that post. It will do.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the default. When you build the solution only the modified projects will be built.