# Visual Studio 2012 project always out of date (.cs modified)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, build

We have one project that is used in nearly all other projects in our solution and for some time the whole solution is always rebuild, because a source file in this one project seems to be modified.

> 1>Project 'Utilities' is not up to date. Input file '[...]\utilities\logging\result.cs' is modified after output file '[...]bin\Debug\Utilities.pdb'.

But the file isn't modified at all nor any other file in this project.

Has anyone a hint for me where the problem could be located? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Could you check what is the timestamp of the file in question? Could it be set by mistake to some future date? This would force a recompile... Refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/2651443/1336068 for more information.

Also, https://stackoverflow.com/a/775272/1336068 has general information on how to avoid rebuilding your code every time you run your application project in visual studio.

Comment: I experienced the twice problem after changing my timezone with the project open when traveling...probably related. After restarting Visual Studio, it builds.

Comment: I had this problem while testing a daylight savings problem and accidentally left the setting turned off (so my clock was 1 hour behind 'actual time.') Turning daylight savings back on fixed the issue.

Comment: @Thomas927 this oddly specific fix solved my issue today haha

Answer (score 2):

I got this message whenever I ran some unit tests for a site. It was a .js JavaScript file that I had edited. It hadn't caused the PDB recompile, so the build always thought this was a modified file, and therefore required a rebuild.

A clean and rebuild fixed this.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting a similar error related to the dll and pdb file. It turned out that there was a circular dependency between projects (ie in the Project References) that was causing the dll to be touched after it was compiled. Removing the unneeded reference fixed it.