# Rebuild of common dependencies when running NUnit tests in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nunit

I have a package `FooTests` that depends on both `Foo` and `Bar`.

`Bar` also depends on `Foo`.

Whenever I change `Foo`, and run `FooTests`, I expect the NUnit VS Test Adapter  to rebuild `Foo`. And that's happening as expected.

However, it is also rebuilding `Bar` even though `Bar` itself didn't change -- the only thing changing is the copy of `Foo.dll` within `Bar`. (I presume that the `Bar.dll` itself doesn't change.)

This gets to be a problem when there are many such intermediate packages between `FooTest` and `Foo`.

Is there any way to short-circuit this behavior to rebuild only those projects that have directly changed and directly impact the test being executed?

I have seen a similar question:

[Unnecessary project rebuilds when unit testing in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23062116/unnecessary-project-rebuilds-when-unit-testing-in-visual-studio)

I am already on Visual Studio 2013 Update 4, and already applied the fix for "copy if newer" -- my question is more precisely about intermediate dependencies.