# Visual Studio - Avoid Unnecessary File Replication

Tags: visual-studio-2010, optimization

get from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8440/visual-studio-optimizations#8473

> The standard setup for .NET solutions is that each assembly gets its
>   own bin directory to which it is copied along with the assemblies of
>   all its dependencies. If your solution contains an .EXE file and, say,
>   40 different assemblies. Does it really make sense to copy the
>   dependencies of each assembly to each separate build directory? The
>   target directory of the EXE should be enough. Another way to
>   accomplish roughly the same would be to give the assemblies common
>   output directories. That also avoids the copying. Some earlier
>   versions of Visual Studio did not support this well, so be careful. I
>   have, however, been using this approach with VS2008 for quite a while
>   without noticing any problems.

question - how to disable creating "bin" etc for all child projects? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Edit** - there is a more comprehensive answer at [Optimizing Visual Studio solution build - where to put DLL files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/488043/optimizing-visual-studio-solution-build-where-to-put-dll-files).

Create top level `/bin/` folders above all your child projects.  Then for each project, right click and go to properties.  On the build tab, you can amend the "Output path" to point to your new top level bin with a relative path (e.g. `../bin/Debug` or `../bin/Release`).  You should do this for each build configuration (e.g. Debug and Release).

This should result in each assembly being copied just once to the same location.

Note I've checked this procedure in VS2008 but I suspect it is similar in 2010.

Comment: so, it's actual if I have only one startup project in soultion?